# Wildcard with final upper bound

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

`Class<? extends Integer>` will compile fine, but `Integer` is a final type so it doesn't make sense to use it as an upper bound (nothing will ever `extend` it).

If you try to use a final type as an upper bound for a type parameter, you will get a  compiler warning:

> The type parameter T should not be bounded by the final type Integer.
>   Final types cannot be further extended

Why would using a final type as an upper bound for a wildcard be perfectly fine, but throw a warning for a type parameter? Why does Java even allow for wildcards to be bounded by a final upper type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Class<Integer>` is not as permissive for assignment as `Class<? extends Integer>`.

For example, this compiles:

```
Class<? extends Number> numberClass = Integer.class;
Class<? extends Integer> integerClass = numberClass.asSubclass(Integer.class);
```

This doesn't:

```
Class<? extends Number> numberClass = Integer.class;
Class<Integer> integerClass = numberClass.asSubclass(Integer.class);
```

Myself, I couldn't get a compiler warning as you do (perhaps you could provide an example and details on your compiler?).

Comment: It seems to me that the compiler could figure out for itself that the `Class<? extends Integer>` returned from your second example is compatible with `Class<Integer>` because `Integer` is final. But I suppose that would add more complexity to the compiler than its worth. Maybe the warning is Eclipse specific: Eclipse Juno w/ JDT 3.8.0.